# How to install section 3 manpages for CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, yum, package-management

I'm trying to read the manpage for read(3) on my CentOS system:

```
$ man read 3
No manual entry for 3
```

What/Which package do I have to install to get these manpages?

(glibc* packages are installed on my system)

Comment: what gives you the impression that there is a `read(3)` man page? see `read(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the man command, the section should be first then the name. Also, the man page for read() on my CentOS 5 system is in section 3p, not 3.

Try:

```
man 3p read
```

Answer (score 6):

```
yum -y install man-pages
```

This will install a large percentage of the programmers' man pages, which do not come by default on a CentOS minimal install.

Answer (score 1):

For programmer man pages on CentOS 7, you also need :-

```
sudo yum install man-pages-overrides
```